# vb6.0 project for airport boarding pass printing

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I'm very new to visual basic 6.0 and I have a very less knowledge in it.
My project is about airport boarding pass generator.

In my first form,I have  a text box for entering PNR by the user. Here, the program has to search for the PNR already stored in a ADODB connected MS access database. IF the PNR entered by the user is right, then it has to go to the next form showing entire details of the passenger and flight, otherwise it should pop up a msg. box saying "invalid PNR".

---

Here is the coding that i used in this program:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\16hu3a120(part2)\BOARDING PASS3.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
conn.Open
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
RS.Open "select * from PID", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
End Sub
Private Sub cmdcancel_Click(Index As Integer)
MsgBox "DO YOU WANT TO CANCEL THE PROCESS?", vbYesNoCancel
End
End Sub
Private Sub cmdconfirm_Click(Index As Integer)
Dim pnr As String
pnr = txtinput.Text
Do
    If (pnr = RS.Fields(0)) Then
    MsgBox "SUCCESSFUL"
    Form1.Show       
    ElseIf (pnr <> RS.Fields(0) & RS.EOF = True) Then
    MsgBox "Invalid PNR", vbRetryCancel
    RS.MoveFirst
    End
    Exit Do
    End If
    RS.MoveNext
Loop While RS.EOF = False
If pnr = "" Then
MsgBox " FIELDS CANNOT BE LEFT EMPTY", vbAbortRetryIgnore
End If
End
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe two hints: Read about SQL. Then, if you get stuck with a specific problem, ask with a reasonable piece of code. Here at SO we share knowledge, but we do not write your program.

Comment: A few more hints: you have "end" in your program a lot.  It really shouldn't be anywhere.  If you want to end the program, `Unload Me` but I don't think that's what you want to do in every case.  Your command button has an index parameter, this implies you have multiple command buttons, but you don't check the index number inside your code, so which one are you clicking?  Your're also using message boxes but not capturing or acting on the responses.  I don't want to discourage you, not too bad for a beginner, but there's more.

Comment: Don't request updateable cursors when you only read.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several errors in it.

In your Cancel button event code, you need to process the return value from the message box and take action accordingly.

```
Private Sub cmdcancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCancel.Click
    '
    If MsgBox("DO YOU WANT TO CANCEL THE PROCESS?", vbYesNoCancel) <> vbNo Then
        'Hide the form and return to main window
        Me.Hide
    End If
    '
End Sub
```

In your Confirm button event code, you need to test for input BEFORE processing the input not at the end of processing!

Also the sequence of actions need to be streamlined so as to complete the objective in the least possible steps/statements.

```
Private Sub cmdconfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdConfirm.Click
    '
    Dim matched as boolean
    Dim pnr As String
    pnr = txtinput.Text
    '
    If pnr = "" Then
        MsgBox("FIELDS CANNOT BE LEFT EMPTY", vbOkay)
    Else
        matched = false
        Do
            If (pnr = RS.Fields(0)) Then
                matched = True
                exit do
            End If
            RS.MoveNext
        Loop While RS.EOF = False
        '
        if matched Then
            MsgBox("SUCCESSFUL")
            Form1.Show
        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid PNR", vbOkay)
            'return to main form
            Me.Hide
        End If
    End If
    '
End Sub
```

Finally, although I have not included it in my code, be sure to dispose of the variables you create and use, in order to avoid a memory leak!